# Use javascript to generate spreadsheet including formulas and user inputs

Tags: javascript, arrays, excel, google-apps-script, download

Using Javascript, I want to let users download or generate a spreadsheet that contains several parameter values they've chosen, as well as formulas that perform calculations using those parameters. After they generate/download the spreadsheet, users need to have the ability to change parameters and potentially customize the formulas.

I've seen that this can probably be done server side, but I think that requires learning yet another new language (I'm learning to code just for this project) so I suspect that's not yet feasible for me in the near future.

My solution thus far has been to convert the spreadsheet into delimited format, then code it into an array of arrays so it can be downloaded as a .csv file when someone clicks on a link.

Unfortunately, I'll need to make somewhat frequent changes to the formulas, and it's a complicated spreadsheet with complicated and repetitive formulas so it's tedious to find where to make changes (to give a sense, the code for the array currently takes up 19 pages when copied into MS Word, 12pt TNR.)

So a few questions:

1. Is there an easier/better way to download or generate a spreadsheet with formulas and user input?
2. If the answer to #1 is no, is there a way to break up an array in the code and make it easier to find/edit an individual cell/value?
3. As an alternative, should I consider switching to Google spreadsheets? Haven't done this because a handful of users might not be able to access Google at work, but the majority can. Maybe the pros outweigh the cons?
4. Is there another idea I haven't considered?

Very much appreciate any suggestions or feedback!